# Why does ontoggle event doesn't work ? (even on google chrome)

Tags: html

I would like to put the `<details>` tag in my page with a pop-up window when cliking on it, so the code would be:

```
<details ontoggle="alert('Hello')">these are some details</details>
```

But after having load the page, if i click on details, no pop-up window...

Is it a current problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using this correctly, but you'll need to surround `Hello` in single quotes instead of double quotation marks.  The first double quotation mark before `"Hello"` ends up malforming the `alert` function call:

`<details ontoggle="alert("`

So try using `<details ontoggle="alert('Hello')">these are some details</details>` instead.

Comment: i just edited my post, the problem isn't about quotes sorry

Comment: @mric750 This is the only issue I'm seeing with the code that you posted.  Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/5h147n01/ .  Try substituting single quotes for double quotes to see for yourself.  Alternatively, you should consider running your code through a linter or look for console errors to see if there's any syntax errors with the code that you posted.